# Split or Group DATA and then kick out unnecessary ones

Tags: r

My Problem is almost completely mentioned in the Title.
I need to group/split data and afterwards kick out the ones that have not the necessary amount of data. Afterwards I want to regress the data in a multiple regression (most likely will use `lm()`).

My Data set has over 50.000 companies which provide data for one year and each line provides data for one firm and each column (have over 30) for one aspect for example sales, asset or  the segment they work in (examples are in the table below).

I need to split them into the segment they are working in because I want to regress afterwards the consumption depending on the marketing spending and because not  every segment is investing ( is necessary to invest) the same amount I need to split them.

| Name | Segment | Sale | Year | Asset | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3401 | 10000 | 2000 | 200000 | x |
| A | 3401 | 20000 | 2001 | 250000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 15000 | 2004 | 280000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 23000 | 2009 | 320000 | x |
| B | 2201 | 28000 | 2010 | 390000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 30000 | 2000 | 210000 | x |
| C | 2201 | 18000 | 2004 | 200000 | x |
| D | 1 | 28000 | 2000 | 400000 | x |
| D | 1 | 38000 | 2001 | 521000 | x |

I tried just simply grouping ( `group_by()`)the data but because of the different amount of segments I can't filter out afterwards per hand the segments that have lower than 10 companies. And if I don't filter it or split it it wont be registered in the regression afterwards.

Hope my questions are clear :):

1. Need to split or group data for the column "segment"
2. Kick out the groups that have not the necessary amount of companies (for significance in the regression)
3. If I don't have split up data I need to have a function that I can use for the regression so that the regression only provides data for each segment (split up data most likely is way to huge to do a regression on each of them)

(4. How can I see how many different segments I have?)

Comment: What do you want to regress? What is your lm formula?

Answer (score 2):

Update on OP request:
You can perform your regression this way: You have to modify the regression here it is only a meanless example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
df %>% 
  mutate(Segment = factor(Segment)) %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  filter(n() > 2) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map_dfr(.f = function(df){
    lm(Sale ~ Asset, data=df) %>% 
      glance() %>% 
      add_column(Segment = unique(df$Segment), .before = 1)
  })
```

```
# A tibble: 1 x 13
  Segment r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC  deviance df.residual  nobs
  <fct>       <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <int> <int>
1 2201       0.0520        -0.264 7173.     0.165   0.712     1  -50.2  106.  105. 154336000           3     5
```

After `filter` I used for this example `4` we could use `group_split` to see the splitted groups:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Segment) %>% 
  filter(n() > 4) %>% 
  group_split()
```

```
  Name  Segment  Sale  Year  Asset Another_header
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>  <int> <chr>         
1 B        2201 15000  2004 280000 x             
2 B        2201 23000  2009 320000 x             
3 B        2201 28000  2010 390000 x             
4 C        2201 30000  2000 210000 x             
5 C        2201 18000  2004 200000 x
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work. Do I have to do anything different in the regression now?

Comment: Tell me your lm formula so for example `lm(Sale ~ Asset, data=df)` or something else and I will show you!

Comment: With the data I provided its every variable and a few more most likely like this:  lm(marketing spending ~ sale(t-1)/asset(t-1) + sale + inflation rate + sale(t-1) + another header, data=Relevante_V03)

Comment: Please see my update. using group_split you get list. you then can iterate over each list and apply your regression like shown in the update!

Comment: Thank you very much :) Just two last questions: 1. can I use the modified regression later on? and 2. just to be clear: I can just set (for example) + interest rate after the asset?

Comment: Yes and yes!:-) Instead of `lm(Sale ~ Asset, data=df)` you can use `lm(marketing spending ~ sale(t-1)/asset(t-1) + sale + inflation rate + sale(t-1) + another header, data=df)`. NOTE: `data=df` not `Relevante_V03` because it is referring to `df` in `function(df)`

Comment: I used your function and it seams to work only issue is that I don't get the coefficients of the regression. I used view() afterwards and it gave me a table with r.squared, adj.r.squared, sigma, statistic, p.value, df( what does that mean?), logLik, AIC, BIC, deviance, df.residual, nobs ( what does that mean?) but not the coefficients with the Estimate, Std. Error, t value and Pr(>|t|) (that would normally be shown with the lm() function)

Answer (score 1):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Segment) %>%
  filter(n() >= 10) %>%   # '10' being some minimum number of rows for regression
  ...
```

### base R

```r
spldat <- split(dat, dat$Segment)
spldat_use <- spldat[ sapply(spldat, nrow) >= 10 ]
```

Comment: If I use group_split() after the dplyr version I get a different result than if I use the base R why? dplyr has length of 257 and base R of 231

Comment: Are you looking at my `spldat` or `spldat_use`? I cannot reproduce your issue, as TarJae's and my answers return the same `list`-of-frames.

Comment: I look at the split_use one

Comment: Are you using TarJae's `>4` and my `>=10`?

Comment: No I used those separately. And just your two options deliver different results

Comment: Yes of course they produce different results! The `dplyr` code returns a whole frame, on which you can do grouped regression within the dplyr verbs (perhaps with `tidyr::nest(..)`), and the second returns a list of frames suitable for `lapply` and family. Forgive me, but you asked for "split or group data", and these do *each of your requests*.

Comment: Sorry I did not want to harm you :/ I was just asking why there is a difference. I am completely new to r so this is my first work on a data set and I could not figure it out why there is a difference and wich one I should choose in the end. Nevertheless thanks for your help

Comment: I'm feeling no harm :-), but you are saying that my code does not work when it does what you ask: one code block *groups* the data (still a single frame) and removes groups that do not have sufficient data (at least 10 rows); the other code block *splits* the data into a list, and removes those sub-frames that do not have at least 10 rows. If my code is not working with data that I don't have, then I feel it is up to you to be able to provide sample data and expected output so that I can try to reproduce and/or try to explain your findings.